# What is the type of '1' constant in C?

Tags: c

What is the type of a `'1'` constant in C? Before any promotions. Is it a `char` or an `int`?

Comment: `1` is `int`, `'1'` is `int` too.

Comment: In C chars are ascii ints

Comment: @pmg The dupe is spot on. Appreciate it.

Comment: To actually answer _why_, it probably got to do with C not having much in the way of a type system back in the days, so they treated everything as `int`.